# Graph theory Maximum edges?

Tags: graph, theory

**If a simple graph has 3 component and  these component have 4,5,6 vertices, then maximum number of edge present in graph.**

> (a) 26
>
> (b) 76
>
> (c) 30
>
> (d) 42

Why do I get a wrong answer if I apply the formula that 'a graph with n vertices and k-connected components has maximum edges `(n-k)(n-k+1)/2`' ?

Can't we take n as 4+5+6=15 and number of components = 3?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: The maximum number of edges is `m ≤ (n-k)(n-k+1)/2` when you get to choose how to distribute the vertices into the `k` components. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075692/number-of-edges-in-a-graph-with-n-vertices-and-k-connected-components. If you are given the number of vertices in a component, then the maximum number of edges is when that component is a complete graph as in [Codor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42758345/1377097).

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, each of the connected components can have at most

```
n*(n-1)/2
```

edges, where `n` is the number of vertices of the respective connected component; the formula is the number of edges of a complete graph with `n` vertices. In total,
one obtains a maximum number of

```
4*3   5*4   6*5
--- + --- + --- = 6 + 10 + 15 = 31
  2     2     2
```

edges (while, surprisingly, this number does not occur in the list of valid answers).